# Limiting app device target in the app store to iPhone only?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm developing an app for the iPhone only, however I notice in the app store it list my app as "Compatibility: Requires iOS 8.1 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch.". When I inspect my project file, it say's devices "iPhone".

When I searching the app store with the same device, I can't find it, however if I follow the link off the website I can install it on the iPad.

Problem is I did not design it for anything else other than the iPhone, so there is some UI issues. Is there somewhere else I need to change something to have the App Sire only list it as iPhone compatible?

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. Every iPhone app can be launched on iPad. It will looks like that:
[image]